# How can I present subcategories within a parent category in prestashop?

Tags: php, html, e-commerce, smarty, prestashop

So as you can in this image, you can hover over the nav button 'Eliquids' and 4 categories will show up in a drop down.

All my products are contained within those four categories, however, if you click on the word 'Eliquids' it's self, it takes you to an empty page being as all the products are stored within their respective category.

On the left you can see the categories being displayed in a side navbar.

How can I make it so all four sub-categories (Chef's Blends, steamgunk etc) show within the category 'Eliquids' ?

Is this possible via the back office as I can't seem to find it my self. Otherwise, is it a case of editing the source code ?

**Version:** Prestashop 1.6.0.9

**Theme:** Prestashop default bootstrap theme

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure that a the "Theme configurator" module. There is "Display subcategories" at the bottom at the "Configure" page.

Comment: Can you check out this additional problem?
http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/385184-image-slider-modual-settings-broken/

Comment: Reply there or here, either would great if possible